# Node.js: rimraf not executing asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am a newbie and am breaking my head over a call that does not seem to be executing asynchronously. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

var myDir= "C:\\DeleteMe";

function doStuff(cb) {
    rimraf(myDir, function (err) {
        console.log("done delete");
        return cb(null);
    });

    console.log("after rimraf");
}

doStuff(function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

The output I get from this is

```
after rimraf
done delete
done
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: That order appears correct to me (message in `doStuff`, message in first cb, message in second cb). What are you expecting?

Comment: Looks pretty asynchronous to me.

Comment: Ouch. You are right. I confused myself. SORRRY I am a newbie to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close, on the grounds that everything is actually working correctly. :) @user2689782, if that's not the case, please update the question.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to close it...

Comment: rather than close, probably worth just deleting.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one with async await support, https://github.com/shinnn/rmfr.

#### npm i rmfr

```
const rmfr = require('rmfr');

(async () => await rmfr('path/to/target'))();
```